# Results from loop don't work correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

1. I want to loop through an array.
2. Any index which has a length larger than 3 I want to abbreviate.
3. I want to place the new abbreviated months into a new array.
4. I want to test that it works by writing the results to the console.

I can get the code to run, however the results don't come out the way I'd hope. From my understanding the loop runs true, running the if statement, which runs true, running the code block. After that the loop should iterate and continue as long as i < months.length, but it doesn't.

```js
var months = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var monthsAbbrev = [];

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
if (months[i].length > 3) {
monthsAbbrev = months[i].slice(0, 3);
}
}

console.log(monthsAbbrev);
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: At OP's level, I'd rather give him this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: The reason it's not working the way you're expecting it to, is that your assignment is to a `char[]` rather than a `string[]` and replacing that array each time.  You can verify this with a `console.log(monthsAbbrev[0]);`.  There are already a number of answers telling you what to do, but not why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the pushing, you can omit the check for length > 3, because slice is already doing it and that prevent to miss some month, like `'May'`.

```js
var months = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var monthsAbbrev = [];

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
    monthsAbbrev.push(months[i].slice(0, 3));
}

console.log(monthsAbbrev);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina...I wouldn't have caught that prior. I really appreciate the feedback and help!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it simply with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var months = ["January", "Febuary"]; //sample data for better understanding
var monthsAbbrev = months.map(v => v.substr(0,3));
console.log(monthsAbbrev); //["Jan", "Feb"]
```

By the way you are not [pushing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) anything into your target array in your code, that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the months to your monthsAbbrev array. One way you can do this is by using the `.push()` function:

```js
var months = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var monthsAbbrev = [];

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  if (months[i].length > 3) {
    monthsAbbrev.push(months[i].slice(0, 3));
  }
}

console.log(monthsAbbrev);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot j08691. This helped a lot and addressed the problem. I'm going to look into the code in more detail and make certain I understand the syntax let alone better understand the push property. Regardless, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just had to push to the array formed. Rest you already had it.

```js
var months = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var monthsAbbrev = [];

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
if (months[i].length > 3) {
monthsAbbrev.push(months[i].slice(0, 3));
}
}

console.log(monthsAbbrev);
```

Comment: Thanks Ayan. I wasn't familiar w/ the push property, but it now makes sense. Your adding the abbreviated month to the monthsAbbrev variable, and then pushing the next variable using the push property. I'm new to code, however I'm really enjoying what I'm learning thus far. I hope to start a Web Development bootcamp come next month. Anyway, thanks again!